# Formatting dictionary entries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm running python 2.7 in PS on a w10. I want to print the key and the value of a dictionary with every pair enumerated.

I do the following:

```
my_dict = {'key_one': 1, 'key_two': 2, 'key_three': 3}

for k, v in enumerate(my_dict.iteritems(), start = 1):
     print k, v
```

which in turn gives:

 `1 ('key_one', 1)
 2 ('key_two', 2)
 3 ('key_three', 3)`

How do I return the entries without the braces?

Example - I want to put a = sign in between my key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the indicies (from enumerate), then you're going to have to unpack the key and value from the dict items separates. Right now what you're calling `k` is actually an index, and what you're calling `v` is actually a key-value pair. Try something like this:

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(my_dict.iteritems(), start=1):
    print i, k, v
```

That results in something like:

```
1 key_two 2
2 key_one 1
3 key_three 3
```

To get them formatted with an equals sign, you'd have to change the print statement to `print i, "{}={}".format(k, v)`, which would result in something like:

```
1 key_two=2
2 key_one=1
3 key_three=3
```

If you need to retrieve the keys in a consistent order, use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), like this:

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(sorted(my_dict.iteritems()), start=1):
    ...
```

Or, if you want to sort by values first instead of the keys first, you could specify a `key` function for the `sorted()` call. That would look like: `sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda (x, y): (y, x))`. That would give you an output of

```
1 key_one=1
2 key_two=2
3 key_three=3
```

Comment: Yes, except it's worth noting that a dictionary is unordered, so enumerating has very limited value

Comment: With that said if I run this script on another machine will the enumeration be different from mine? I noticed that the order in which the pairs are typed in changes if I call the iteritems() on a dict...

Comment: @beetroot Yes. That is by design. Python does not guarantee that the items in a dict will be retrieved in any particular order (this has to do with the way dictionaries are typically implemented at a low level). If you want to get a consistent ordering, you could sort the items. See my edit to the answer to see how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `enumerate` if you just want to print the existing key and values in your dictionary. Just use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print '{} = {}'.format(k, v)
```

This would give:

```
key_one = 1
key_two = 2
key_three = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
my_dict = {'key_one': 1, 'key_two': 2, 'key_three': 3}
for key,value in my_dict.iteritems():
    print key,value
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
>>> for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
...      print k, v
... 
key_two 2
key_one 1
key_three 3
```

or

```
>>> for i, (k, v) in enumerate(my_dict.iteritems(), start=1):
...     print i, k, v
... 
1 key_two 2
2 key_one 1
3 key_three 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `enumerate()` here. It is used when you need to *iterate* along with the *index*. you do not even need `str.format()` for achieving this. Simply place a entry of `'='` string between your `key`, `value` and you will get what your desire. For example:

```
>>> my_dict = {'key_one': 1, 'key_two': 2, 'key_three': 3}
>>> for key, value in my_dict.items():
...     print key, '=', value
... 
key_two = 2
key_one = 1
key_three = 3
```

---

*Edit: Based on the comment at [user3030010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431131/2063361)*

Note: `dict` in python are un ordered. In case you want to maintain the order, use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead. It will preserve the order independent of the platform and python version. For example if you created the `dict` like:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> my_dict = OrderedDict()
>>> my_dict['key_one'] = 1
>>> my_dict['key_two'] = 2
>>> my_dict['key_three'] = 3
```

On iterating it, you will always get the same response as:

```
>>> for key, value in my_dict.items():
...     print key, '=', value
... 
key_one = 1
key_two = 2
key_three = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple *one-line* solution(for Python 2.7):

```
print '\n'.join([k+'='+ str(my_dict[k]) for k in my_dict.keys()])
```

The output:

```
key_two=2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
key_one=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
key_three=3
```